# Do opponents die if you don't perform a fatality?

Tags: mortal-kombat-series

In the *Mortal Kombat* franchise when the health bar of the opponent reaches zero in the final round they develop a vertigo, a vocie says FINISH HIM and you have three choices:

- You can wait until the opponent hits the ground and you win.
- You can punch or kick the opponent once, and again they hit the ground and you win.
- You can perform a finishing move (known as fatality) to brutally kill the opponent, and you win.

**My question**: Do the opponents die in the first two choices or they just knock out? Is there any explanation by the game developers?

Comment: This seems like a question about developer intent

Comment: @Stevoisiak Is it not allowed here? In Movies and TV SE it's accepted to ask about explanation by the movie staff about a matter. Because it's not opinion-based and it can be researched in reliable sources. But I don't know about here

Comment: Take a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)